# Preventing hardware back button android for React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I want to prevent the user from going back to the previous screen. So I added code, but this does not work. Are there any solutions for this? The alert pop up is seen but "return false" does not work.

```
componentDidMount() {
   BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
     Alert.alert("alert","alert")

      this.props.navigator.pop();

       return false;
   });
```

Comment: There is very little context in your question. Please go through the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and improve your post. Thanks.

Comment: Try removing `this.props.navigator.pop();`

Answer (score 144):

You need to **return true**, if you want to disable the default back button behavior.

Here is a sample component which will block the user from going back to previous screen.

```
import React, {Component,} from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    BackHandler,
    ToastAndroid,
} from 'react-native';

class BackButtonDemo extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
    }

    handleBackButton() {
        ToastAndroid.show('Back button is pressed', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        return true;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Back button example</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = BackButtonDemo;
```

**Note:**

Also remove `this.props.navigator.pop();` from your solution.

`Navigator` pop function will take the user to the previous screen rendered by `Navigator`.

Comment: BackAndroid is now deprecated. You should use BackHandler. It uses the same event listener methods so its not a huge change.

Comment: How can I make it configurable for a single screen ?

Comment: I want to desable only hardware and virtual back button press, but maintain header back Button from react-navigation working. That answer works fine too? Or this desable all back touch events (in header and Android Button, virtual and phisic)?

Comment: `return true` is the key

Comment: What does `return true` do? Can you please tell?

Answer (score 67):

*Shiny* new implementation using [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html):

```js
import React, {Component, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    BackHandler,
} from 'react-native';

const LogInView = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
      const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => true)
      return () => backHandler.remove()
    }, [])

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Back button example</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

export default LoginView
```

Comment: This code works perfectly, but is there a way to apply it universally to the whole app?
I have added this code in `App.js` file but that doesn't apply it globally for some reason. I had to add it to each screen separately.

Comment: Sorry @sj_959 that I never saw this comment. You can put it in a helper file and import from there? Although probably a little late to the party now...

Comment: Yes, that should do it @Rambatino. Thanks.

Comment: First `() => true` and second `() => true` don't have the same reference. Hence effectively you never remove the added event listener.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please and/or link to docs?

Comment: @MichaelS so you're saying the examples in the docs are wrong: https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler?

Comment: No. The docs are correct. The answer isn't matching the docs

Comment: That's changed since I last looked

Comment: its working but this functionality is applying on next screens too ? how can we avoid it ?

Comment: @MahishDino remove event listener before navigating to next page and re-add on return

Answer (score 18):

I disable my back button (android) for whole application by add this code in App.js

```
componentDidMount() {
  BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  BackAndroid.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
}

handleBackButton() {
  return true;
}
```

don't forget to import BackAndroid

```
import {BackAndroid} from 'react-native'
```

Comment: Thank You! This worked but I get warning message,Then I used "BackHandler" instead of "BackAndroid"  on your answer. Then worked fine without any warnings.

Comment: I don't think this will work often because subscriptions are called in reverse order, so if there is another code (or 3rd party library) that has subscribed some other event, then that event will be triggered on the back press. So even if you subscribed your event at root level, it won't work every time. It is stated here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler

Comment: yours should be caused by different version of react native. maybe on the time this answer was posted, it's still using "BackAndroid", but then they planning to change to "BackHandler". As for now, i am on react native 0.60, the "BackAndroid" is completely gone and i have to use "BackHandler"

Answer (score 9):

Try this Disable back button by just returning true

```
import {BackAndroid} from 'react-native';

componentWillMount() {
   BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {return true});
}
```

Comment: BackAndroid is deprecated now

Answer (score 7):

So While Everyone is working with the Backhandler of **react-native** I tried to do it with **react-navigation** to prevent going back handler.
This worked for me.
If you just want to prevent going back without showing or alerting anything to the user.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }, [navigation]);
```

You can put this code in your function component.

*Use Case:*

> In User Registration when the user signup and go to the confirmation
> screen for the code so we dont want him back you can use this code at
> the moment.

Answer (score 6):

Just to give you a complete answer when using **react-navigation**:

If you're using react-navigation, place the following in your **RootNavigation class** not the App.js in order to disable the back-button for the whole application.

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackButtonPressed);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackButtonPressed);
}

onBackButtonPressed() {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

using the BackHandler from react native worked for me. Just include this line in your ComponentWillMount:

```
BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {return true})
```

it will disable back button on android device.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using **react-natigation** then you need to use `BackHandler` instead of `BackAndroid`

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

// code

componentDidMount() {
  BackHandler.addEventListener('backPress');
}

// some more code

componentWillUnmount() {
  BackHandler.removeEventListener('backPress');
}
```

Comment: yes, BackHandler, because BackAndroid is deprecated

Answer (score 4):

For those who are commenting under answers and trying to find a code which will disable the back click only on a specific screen not for entire application, here is the code. You are welcome.

```js
useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
        const onBackPress = () => {
            return true;
        };
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);
    
        return () =>
            BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);
    }, []),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Disable back button for module react-navigation, use hook useFocusEffect

```
const hardwareBackPressCustom = useCallback(() => {
        return true;
    }, []);

useFocusEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', hardwareBackPressCustom)
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', hardwareBackPressCustom)
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was the solution:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'

function Home({ navigation }) {
    useEffect(() =>
        navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            return
        }),
        [navigation]
    );


    return (
        <View>
            
            ...

        </View>
    )
}

export default Home
```

You can see an example in [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back/)

Answer (score 1):

The only correct solution can be found here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-android-back-button-handling/

```
function ScreenWithCustomBackBehavior() {
  // ...

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const onBackPress = () => {
        return true;
      };

      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);

      return () =>
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);
    }, [isSelectionModeEnabled, disableSelectionMode])
  );

  // ...
}
```

All the others are for class components or apply to all screens, rather than only the screen where the hook is applied.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {BackHandler} from 'react-native';
    
useEffect(() => {

const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
        'hardwareBackPress',
        () => {
          return true;
        },
      );
      return () => backHandler.remove();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're encountering with `return false` not working is because the `BackAndroid` API has been deprecated in favor of the `BackHandler` API in recent versions of React Native.

To prevent action on hardware back press, you can use the BackHandler API. Here is a *custom hook* that you could use inside your navigation screen.

the code:

```js
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

/**
 * Hook that handles Android back button presses and returns the callback
 */
export function useAndroidBackButtonHandler(handler: any) {
  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handler);
      return () => BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handler);
    }, [handler])
  );
}
```

And use it in your navigation screen like this:

```js
const YourComponent = () => {
.
.
.
  const handleBackPress = (): boolean => {
    ToastAndroid.show('Back button press is disabled', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    return true;
  };

  useAndroidBackButtonHandler(handleBackPress);
.
.
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for Version 6.x as seen in [RN docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-android-back-button-handling/)

```
  function ScreenWithCustomBackBehavior() {
  // ...

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const onBackPress = () => {
        if (isSelectionModeEnabled()) {
          disableSelectionMode();
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      };

      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);

      return () =>
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);
    }, [isSelectionModeEnabled, disableSelectionMode])
  );

  // ...
}
```

Alternatively as a hook

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {useEffect, useState, useCallback} from 'react';

export const usePreventGoBack = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [allow, setAllow] = useState(false);

  const beforeRemoveListener = useCallback(
    e => {
      if (allow) {
        return;
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    },
    [allow],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', beforeRemoveListener);
    return () => {
      unsub();
    };
  }, [navigation, beforeRemoveListener, allow]);

  return (cb: () => void) => {
    setAllow(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      cb();
    });
  };
};
```

To bypass

```
 const continuePressed = () => {
    allowBackButton(() => {
      navigation.popToTop();
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple hook to deal with it:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { BackHandler } from "react-native";

type BackHandlerFunction = () => boolean;

export function useBackHandler(handler?: BackHandlerFunction) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      "hardwareBackPress",
      () => {
        if (handler) {
          return handler();
        }
        return true;
      }
    );

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, [handler]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For IOS use this code... In the Stack Navigation. react-navigation > 5

```
<LoginStackNav.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{gestureEnabled: false }}/>
```

Answer (score -4):

Onclick of hardware back button OnBackPressed callback gets called

you can just remove super declaration in onBackPressed call back.

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }
```

Comment: That is android java code, this is a react native question.