# Preventing hardware backbutton to goback previous page

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

This question was asked before in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40145301/preventing-hardware-back-button-android-for-react-native)

However, componentDidMound() method prevents rendering page.
I have already changed `BackAndroid` to `BackHandler` but I couldn't manage it.

Also, what is `ToastAndroid`?

EDIT:
 I have used

```
componentWillUnmount(){
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() { preventClose(); });
    }

componentDidMount() {
            BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() { preventClose(); });
      }
preventClose(){
    BackHandler.exitApp();
}
```

But it has bugs. When I move from my page to another page, if I press back button I immediately close the app. (I don't want this to happen. I just want to prevent the user from going back from my main screen, not other stack screens.)

Comment: So you just want that nothing happens when clicking the back button of your device?

Comment: @AppPhil  I want to prevent the user from going previous stack page. Because I have a drawer in which he can log off and go to that screen (login screen).

Answer (score 7):

That should be very basic. In you activity you just need to override the `onBackPressed()` method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // super.onBackPressed(); <- this line of code will make you go back to the previous "page"

    // now you can insert additional code, if you want to do it.
}
```

As long as you don't add `super.onBackPressed();` this will prevent from going back to previous page.

Comment: Please also explain what is [Toast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) to him since he has asked

Answer (score 3):

You can simply override onBackPressed() and comment super method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    // super.onBackPressed(); -> Just comment that line this will prevent device back button action.
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Should I use this function inside a class? If I use it it gives me unexpected token error

Comment: Yes you can just override this function in your activity class.

Comment: I've checked the syntax, I just copy pasted

public void onBackPressed() {

    // super.onBackPressed(); -> Just comment that line this will prevent device back button action.
 }

Still, error

Comment: Ok , your class is extends Activity or Fragment or something else?

Comment: it extends React.Component

Comment: Ohoo, actually onBackPressed is function of Activity component not another. so you can use 
BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
    return false;
});

Comment: Hey! You stole that code from my answer! I mean it is my comment, why would you copy it, you can also delete your post if it is duplicate :)

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you help me? @creativecreatorormaybenot

Comment: No Bro , I haven`t copy your code. I just put the logic here. There is nothing like for copy your code.

Comment: @Eurus You call `.exitApp()`, but that closes your app.

Comment: Well, let me put it in other words.
In my login screen, if the user presses the back button, I want to close the application, not go back to the previous screen.
However, if I use the code above, after the user goes another screen from my login screen, if he presses the back button, it closes the application. I don't want him to close application at that point. I just want him to go back to the previous screen. @creativecreatorormaybenot

Answer (score 1):

As the others mentioned you can override the onBackPressed() method and just let it empty. Then the back button has no functionality.

If you are switching between two activities and the user should not go back to the first activity you can also finish the first activity and then you do not need to override onBackPressed.

You can finish an activity by just calling finish() method after starting the new activity.

Comment: I like this approach too, but he did not asks to finish the other activity, he may want to still use it.