# How to disable the react-native hardware back button?

Tags: android, react-native

How to disable the react-native hardware back button on the entire (Android) App?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing hardware back button android for React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40145301/preventing-hardware-back-button-android-for-react-native)

Comment: componentWillMount() {
    BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {return true});
}

Comment: this code is working for me

Answer (score 2):

You can use [BackHandler](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler.html)

All you need to do is `return true` in your event listener.

```
componentDidMount() {
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backPress)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backPress)
}

backPress = () => true
```

Comment: I want use this for entire app, not for single component.. i tried this in app.js but not getting where do i use this method ..?? @Dan

Answer (score 1):

To block the android back button in your entire app, you can override the `onBackPressed` class method inside your project's `MainActivity.java` file.

This file will probably be in a path like: `android/app/src/main/java/YOUR/PACKAGE/NAME/MainActivity.java`.

Then at bottom of the `MainActivity` class you can simply add the `onBackPressed` override.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Overriding the onBackPressed method and do nothing.

```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
                }
```