# How do I get my app to make use of the Android back button or onPress of a button?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

How do I get my app to make use of the Android back button or onPress of a button?

My relevant packages:

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import incomingCallScreen from "./screens/incomingCall/incomingCallScreen";
import bookingScreen from "./screens/booking/bookingScreen";


const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Loading: LoadingScreen,
  Splash: splashScreen,
  mainFlow: createStackNavigator({
    IncomingCall: incomingCallScreen,
    Booking: bookingScreen
  }),
},
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Loading',
  },
 
  );


const App = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);

export default () => {
  return (
    <App />
  );
};
```

Then in my BookingScreen, when i click a button, it slides right to the IncomingCall screen, BUT i cant use the back button no Android or the Decline button to slide back. Or go back at all.

My **Booking.js** screen:

```
import React, { Component, useEffect } from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, StatusBar, View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { withNavigation } from "react-navigation"; 


function BookingScreen(props)  {

     const today = () => {
        return (

 <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }}>
                                    <MaterialIcon
                                        name="call"
                                        size={20}
                                        color={Colors.primaryColor}
                                        onPress={() => props.navigation.push('IncomingCall')}
                                        style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-end', marginLeft: Sizes.fixPadding }}
                                    />
                                </View>

      )
    }

}

export default withNavigation(BookingScreen);
```

And then in the **IncomingCall.js** screen:

```
    import React, {Component, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
    import {View, Text, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, BackHandler, Pressable} from 'react-native';
    import { withNavigation } from "react-navigation";;
    import { TransitionPresets } from 'react-navigation-stack';
    
    function IncomingCallScreen(props) {
    
      
      const onDecline = () => {
        navigation.goBack();
        return true;
      };
    
      return (
    <View style={styles.row}>
            {/* Decline Button */}
            <Pressable onPress={onDecline} style={styles.iconContainer}>
              <View style={styles.iconButtonContainer}>
                <Feather name="x" color="white" size={40} />
              </View>
              <Text style={styles.iconText}>Decline</Text>
            </Pressable>
      )
   }  

    IncomingCallScreen.navigationOptions = () => {
      return {
          header: () => null,
          ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
      }
    }
    
    export default withNavigation(IncomingCallScreen);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing hardware back button android for React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40145301/preventing-hardware-back-button-android-for-react-native)

Comment: No, I would LIKE to be able to use the back button, not disable it. The code i've attached doesn't work. I wanted to kknow whats wrong with it.

Comment: Looking at your code you did import BackHandler but havent used it anywhere ? Maybe you missed pasting that part or @chai86

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `navigation.push('IncomingCall')` like you are, instead use `navigation.navigate('IncomingCall')`. This will push the screen onto the stack of screens, you do not have to do it manually. Additionally, every time a user wants to go back a screen, you should use `navigation.goBack()`, which I see you already are. This should allow Android users to user the physical buttons on their devices.

Comment: Can i use navigation.navigate with React navigation v4?

Comment: Yes. Docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigation-actions#navigate